# WPF style button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I've tried to change style for mouseover event.

Here's my styles code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NavigationButton" 
           TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#295fa6"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

and I used it in that way:

```
<Button x:Name="test"
        Grid.Column="0"" 
        Style="{StaticResource NavigationButton}">
        <Image Source="Assets/imaaa.png" />
 </Button>
```

and mouseover still has default color

Comment: Because default template uses animations (to a fixed value) to change background and that has almost highest priority in [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx#listing). For that you need to change default template

Comment: It has been already answered at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747709/syleproblem-cant-change-background-of-particular-button
Moreover buttons has a default control template applied to it and the mousehover behavior comes from there. You may want to read about it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to modify the ControlTemplate. To remove the default behaviour on the Button.

```
<Style x:Key="NavigationButton" 
           TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="#295fa6"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="#295fa6">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
           <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```