# XAML Theme not getting the Background color property

Tags: xaml, styles, themes

I have a button that uses my own theme by using style= I want the theme code to pick up and use the Background color property but everything I've tried always fetches black #000000 from the XAML code.

I use it like this:

`<Button Background="#844eff" Style="{StaticResource PosButtonTheme}" Content="Return&#x0a;Sale" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,44,0,0" />`

My theme code looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       x:Key="PosButtonTheme">
      
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                   
                     <StackPanel
                        Margin="0,0,0,0">
                         <Border Width="62" Height="62">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint ="0,0" EndPoint ="1,2">
                                    <GradientStop Color= "{TemplateBinding Property=Background}" Offset="0.0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color= "#FFFFAF" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>

                            <Border.Clip>
                                <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="7" RadiusY="10" Rect="0,0,62,62"/>
                             </Border.Clip>
                            <Grid>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text= "{TemplateBinding Property=Content}" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Barlow Semi Condensed SemiBold" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin=" 0,15,0,0"/> 
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel> 
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
     </Style.Setters>
 </Style>
```

The "{TemplateBinding Property=Content}" works fine in the TextBlock but "{TemplateBinding Property=Background}" seems to do nothing its always black or #000000

Any ideas?

Comment: where you define the BackGround property?

Answer (score 0):

You code is ok, so I think you miss to set the BackGround property.
This is what I tried:

```
Background = Brushes.Red;
```

[image]

and then

```
Background = Brushes.Blue;
```

[image]

if this not work for you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6748306/3464775